# Can't find the pub sub service account that will write from bucket to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, devops, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I am relatively new to Google Cloud and am trying to set up a pipeline from DataFlow to BigQuery. I was trying to use pub/sub for this.

So here's what I wanted to achieve:

```
DataFlow -> Data Manipulation using some script (probably Python) -> Bucket (temporary) -> Pub Sub -> BigQuery
```

I have looked into a bunch of pipelines and docs and I was trying to create a subscription that would take my data from bucket to BQ. However, when I try to create it, it keeps saying the service account associated does not have the right perms.
[image: Screenshot of missing service account]

I tried looking for it in the IAM but can't seem to find the account. I also tried adding principal in pub sub permissions directly.

Nothing is working. Help.

Comment: Hi Poala - Can you describe a bit more what your use case is for using Cloud Pub/sub and GCS? Dataflow uses the Beam SDK which has a Bigquery IO - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-bigquery - that you can use to write directly to Bigquery from DF.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a [PubSub to BigQuery subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery), your PubSub servcie account should have relevant IAM permissions for BigQuery access - see [Pub/Sub service account permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#service_account_permissions) and [Assign BigQuery roles to the Pub/Sub service account](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-subscription#assign_bigquery_service_account)

A picture in your question has a sentence in red font with the service account name - `service-69802119849@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. If you work through UI console, you may go to your target BigQuery dataset - `clq` I reckon, and add `BigQuery Data Editor` role and `BigQuery Metadata Viewer` role to that service account, so it has permissions to work with the given dataset. If you would like, you may grant those roles on the project level.

Coming back to a design of the pipeline - I don't know your context and requirements, but as a general observation - if you already have to use a Dataflow, it may be posible to 'stream' data directly to BigQuery without an intermediate storage in a bucket.

Comment: Actually, I want to modify the data before pushing it to BigQuery. And that's where the bucket comes in. Is there a way to do that without the bucket?

Comment: So the original question was misleading. As I don't know your context, scope, requirements, times, team skills, it is very difficult to suggest something useful. You may like to modify the Dataflow job, so it modifies the data as you need and stream it directly into the BigQuery. Or you may prefer using Cloud Composer; or your existing Dataflow streams into BigQuery directly but in some 'staging' tables, and you use SQL based mechanisms for further processing. TBC

Comment: Or you might prefer to use PubSub and Cloud Functions which can modify the run in real time and stream into the BigQuery. Or use a Cloud Run if Cloud Functions are not good enough in your case. There are plenty of options - depends on your situation - context, scope, functional and non functional requirements, time and finance restrictions including CAPEX/OPEX, who and how is going to support the solution in BAU after commissioning, etc.